# Lex: How do I Prevent it from matching against substrings?

Tags: c, lex

For example, I'm supposed to convert "int" to "INT". But if there's the word "integer", I don't think it's supposed to turn into "INTeger".

If I define `"int" printf("INT");` the substrings are matched though. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following captures what you want.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

ws                      [\t\n ]

%%

{ws}int{ws}         { printf ("%cINT%c", *yytext, yytext[4]); }
.                       { printf ("%c", *yytext); }
```

To expand this beyond word boundaries (`{ws}`, in this case) you will need to either add modifiers to `ws` or add more specifc checks.

Comment: That will change "stint" so maybe you need the ws at both ends. Also what about things like int*x?

Answer (score 1):

well, here's how i did it:

```
(("int"([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+)|(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+"int")) ECHO;
"int" printf("INT");
```

better suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Lex will choose the rule with the longest possible match for the current input. To avoid substring matches you need to include an additional rule that is longer than `int`. The easiest way to do to this is to add a simple rule that picks up any string that is longer than one character, i.e. `[a-zA-Z]+`. The entire lex program would look like this:-

```
%%

[\t ]+          /* skip whitespace */
int { printf("INT"); }
[a-zA-Z]+       /* catch-all to avoid substring matches */

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   yylex();
   }
```